# How to change db.properties in activiti 5.14

Tags: database, postgresql, h2, activiti

I want to use postgresql instead of H2. What should I do ? I couldn't find a file that was name db.properties in activiti-5.14 folder. I'm waiting your helps
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what style of building a process engine you are using.
You can use default way:
`ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine()` in java and 
then configure *activiti.cfg.xml* file with your postgresql parameters

Or if use spring framework, then create process engine as bean by container and set into it your postrgesql *dataSource* bean.

More info in http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#demo.setup.one.minute.version

Comment: I configured activiti.cfg.xml file with my postgresql parameters but now I have a new problem "Connection is broken: "session closed"?

Comment: Probably the real problem is something else, this is only a result. Try find real problem why session is closed. F.e.: Look at complete stack trace.